# Decryption using blowfish failing

Tags: java, encryption, blowfish

I have a java class file which is used to encrypt/decrypt plain text using blowfish. Below is the code

```java
public class AES {
        
    public static String encrypt(String strClearText,String strKey) {
        String strData="";
    
    try {
        System.out.println("Inside encrypt function");
        System.out.println("text to be encrypted:"+strClearText);
        SecretKeySpec skeyspec=new SecretKeySpec(strKey.getBytes(),"Blowfish");
        Cipher cipher=Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeyspec);
        System.out.println("Encrypt key is:"+strKey);
        byte[] encrypted=cipher.doFinal(strClearText.getBytes());
        strData=new String(encrypted);
        System.out.println("Encrypt value is:"+strData);
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        
    }
    return strData;
}

public static String decrypt(String strEncrypted,String strKey) {
    String strData="";
    
    try {
        System.out.println("Inside decrypt function");
        SecretKeySpec skeyspec=new SecretKeySpec(strKey.getBytes(),"Blowfish");
        Cipher cipher=Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeyspec);
        System.out.println("text to be decrypted:"+strEncrypted);
        System.out.println("Decrypt key is:"+strKey);
        byte[] decrypted=cipher.doFinal(strEncrypted.getBytes());
        strData=new String(decrypted);
        System.out.println("Decrypt value is:"+strData);
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now I am calling the same functions from a jsp and the encrypt functions works as expected but the decrypt function throws the following error

```
<text to be encrypted:TEST>
<Encrypt key is:JOWPRWVH5TU6T4VC>
<Encrypt value is:?U????Q8>
<Inside decrypt function>
<text to be decrypted:?U????Q8>
<Decrypt key is:JOWPRWVH5TU6T4VC>
<javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
```

I understand that this error generally occurs when using the wrong key during decryption but I am using the same key as below

```js
AES sbv =new AES();
String opmsg=sbv.encrypt("TEST","JOWPRWVH5TU6T4VC");
String opmsg1=sbv.decrypt(opmsg,"JOWPRWVH5TU6T4VC");
```

Can anyone please to resolve this issue.

Comment: Encode the ciphertext to base64 before send and decode after recieve.

Comment: @kelalaka you mean in the java function or in the jsp ?

Comment: In the Java function instead of `strData=new String(encrypted);` do https://www.baeldung.com/java-base64-encode-and-decode

Comment: Please indicate the JavaScript library that you are using. That Java code uses ECB and is not cryptographically secure, and it uses no specific encoding for the key bytes.